# How stop alertDialog excecution

Tags: android

I need to stop the excecution app, until the user click OK.
This's my method...

```
public void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje)
{
    final Message NO_HANDLER = null;
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Atención");
    alertDialog.setMessage(mensaje);
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          alertDialog.setButton("OK",NO_HANDLER) ;   
          alertDialog.dismiss();
       }
    });
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.listo);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to halt execution when the dialog is created and wait until the user clicks Ok before continuing?

Comment: stop the application until the user click ok

Comment: Why not use 'alertDialog.setCancelable(false);'?

Comment: you need another activity/fragment to go on when the user clicks

Comment: You want to pause the activity while the alert dialog is shown? If so you can override the onWindowFocusChange method in your activity and put some code in there that pauses/resumes whatever ongoing thing in your activity that you want to freeze. If this is not what you want, please try to refrase your question to make it nore clear what you're after.